# Time code and filename prefix in VLC

Tags: time, filenames, vlc, libvlc, scene

I find this material, http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Play_HowTo/Format_String. I try the time code of the video in my filename prefix like this, "scene-$T-". But the scene filter does not output time code in the file name. Do those format string variables only support 0.9.0 version?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a bug over this module, so I just write a separate function to extract the time info.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look @ the documentation on [this page](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Snapshots/) and variables, for me for example

1. Tools -> Preferences
2. Video
3. On the snapshot section I put $N- which is the name of the file, you could actually do whatever you want with following [variables](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Play_HowTo/Format_String/)

[image]

Comment: did not work for me using the latest stable version (2.1.6) of vlc player on ubuntu 14.04 lts. accepts the parameter as constant strings.

Comment: Actually there is a bug about snapshots that is not working for me either... https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=712935 hope it'll be fixed soon, maybe it has to do with the fact its not working for you

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your questions whether you refer to taking video snapshots, but that's what I'll assume here.

Looking at the documentation (https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Snapshots/), --snapshot-path and --snapshot-prefix can only be expanded from version 2.2.0. I.e. if you want to insert time and date as part of your snapshot filename, you will have to use VLC version 2.2.0 or greater.

A number of Linux distributions have not upgraded their stock VLC to 2.2.0, including Linux Mint, and, it seems Ubuntu. What you're trying to do works for me on Windows with the latest VLC.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Tools->Preferences or alternatively press Ctrl + P

Then Goto Video -> Video snpashot

Enter in Prefix text box

```
vlcsnap-%H-%M-%S
```

Options expansions that can be added are

```
%Y : year
%m : month
%d : day
%H : hour
%M : minute
%S : second
```

For a list of other common formatted string option, Goto

https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Play_HowTo/Format_String

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$N-%H-%M-%S-
```

it works for me while using build 3.0.3